# Setting a default start function for your python project

Tags: python, eclipse

Python newbiew here. Please bear with me.

Having written some good chunk of code one thing bothers me is that I cannot find a way to tell eclipse that this file/funciton is the starting point for my project (test).

I step into code during debugging and end up in some file deep in the code. Then if I want to run it again I go to the tab containing the start file and run it again. It would be nice to be able to specify a "main" function for a python project like we do in C for e.g.

Is something like that possible? If not can I at least tell eclipse to use that one file as the starting point for the project?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand your problem.
If you want to make a "main" function like C, you can do that :

```
def main(argv=None):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify which file to run in Eclipse project, go to menu run -> run configurations.

To specify which function to run, use following idiom within the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    name_of_main_function_to rune
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also name one of your files `__main__.py`.